# jQuery. Prefix selector for various items

Tags: jquery, prefix

How to optimize this?

```
$('link[href="dir/style.css"]').attr("href", "dir/style2.css");
$('link[href="../../dir/style.css"]').attr("href", "../../dir/style2.css");
jQuery('link[href="../dir/style.css"]').attr("href", "../dir/style2.css");
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A better place to ask this question would be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('link[href*="dir/style.css"]').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref.replace('dir/style.css', 'dir/style2.css');
});
```

That uses the [attribute-contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector to select the elements, then passes a function to the call to `.attr()` to return the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same in a single call to `attr` using the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('link[href$="style.css"]').attr('href', function(index, value) {
    return value.replace('style.css', 'style2.css');
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/asAAd/)

Answer (score 0):

That depends of your project structure, but you could do something like this

```
$('a[href*="dir/style.css"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
       // return a version of the href that replaces "style." with "style2."
    return href.replace('style.', 'style2.');
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dT8j6/123/